# [String : Any]の結合方法

Tags: swift, json

[String : Any]の結合方法

swiftで開発しております。
jsonファイルを作成する処理を作成しているのですが

```
class ResultJson {
    func string(result: Result, size: CGPoint) -> String {
        let tracked = result.bodies?.first { $0.joints3D != nil }
        let bodies = [tracked].compactMap { $0 }
        let point2DGroups = bodies.map { $0.point2DDictionary }
        let point3DGroups = bodies.map { $0.point3DDictionary }
        let dict: [String : Any] = ["point2DGroups": point2DGroups,
                                    "point3DGroups": point3DGroups,
                                    "cameraResolution": size.dictionary
        ]
        
        var jsonString = ""
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
            jsonString = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return jsonString
    }
}
```

上記のように構造体データを1データのみjsonファイルに変換するのではなく、
全データをjsonファイルに変更すべく以下のようにコードを編集しました。

```
class ResultJson {
    func string(result: Result, size: CGPoint) -> String {
        let trackeds = result.bodies?.filter { $0.joints3D != nil }
        let point2DGroups[String : Any];
        let point3DGroups[String : Any];
        trackeds.forEach { tracked in
            let bodies += [tracked].compactMap { $0 }
            point2DGroups += bodies.map { $0.point2DDictionary }
            point3DGroups += bodies.map { $0.point3DDictionary }
        }
        let dict: [String : Any] = ["point2DGroups": point2DGroups,
                                    "point3DGroups": point3DGroups,
                                    "cameraResolution": size.dictionary
        ]
        
        
        var jsonString = ""
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
            jsonString = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return jsonString
    }
}
```

しかし、[String : Any]でビルドエラーが出ている状態です。
[String : Any]の結合はどのように行えばよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 質問者さんの環境と第三者の環境で必ずしも同じエラーが出るとは限らないため、可能であればエラーメッセージも質問文にコピペしていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

全体像、期待している結果がわからないため、基本的なSwiftのエラー(構文)を直しました。
これで少しエラーがわかりやすいと思います。

```swift
class ResultJson {
  func string(result: Result, size: CGPoint) -> String {
    let trackeds = result.bodies?.filter { $0.joints3D != nil }
    let point2DGroups: [String: Any] = [:]
    let point3DGroups: [String: Any] = [:]
    
    trackeds?.forEach { tracked in
      let bodies = [tracked].compactMap { $0 }
      point2DGroups += bodies.map { $0.point2DDictionary }
      point3DGroups += bodies.map { $0.point3DDictionary }
    }
    
    let dict: [String : Any] = [
      "point2DGroups": point2DGroups,
      "point3DGroups": point3DGroups,
      "cameraResolution": size.dictionary
    ]
    
    var jsonString = ""
    do {
      let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
      jsonString = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }
    return jsonString
  }
}
```

### 別解: Codable(Encodable, JSONEncoder)

SwiftではJSONを扱う際には、Codableがおすすめです。
以下のように型安全を使いつつJSONを出力(Encode)することが可能です。

```swift
class ResultJson {
  func string() -> String {
    let output = OutputResult(
      point2D: .init(x: 1, y: 2),
      point3D: .init(x: 1, y: 2, z: 3),
      cameraResolution: .init(x: 1, y: 2)
    )
    
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = try! encoder.encode(output)
    
    let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    
    return jsonString
//  {
//    "point3D": {
//      "x": 1,
//      "z": 3,
//      "y": 2
//    },
//    "point2D": {
//      "x": 1,
//      "y": 2
//    },
//    "cameraResolution": {
//      "x": 1,
//      "y": 2
//    }
//  }
  }
}

struct Point2D: Encodable {
  let x: Int
  let y: Int
}

struct Point3D: Encodable {
  let x: Int
  let y: Int
  let z: Int
}

struct OutputResult: Encodable {
  let point2D: Point2D
  let point3D: Point3D
  let cameraResolution: Point2D
}
```